# Pass kwargs to starmap while using Pool in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, threadpool, python-multiprocessing

I'm using Pool to multithread my programme using starmap to pass arguments.

I'm stuck because I cannot seem to find a way to pass kwargs along with the **zip** arrays that I'm passing in the starmap function.

```
pool = Pool(NO_OF_PROCESSES)
branches = pool.starmap(fetch_api, zip(repeat(project_name), api_extensions))
```

The branches request is **incomplete** as I'm still not able to figure out how to pass keywords arguments.

```
def fetch_api(project_name, api_extension, payload={}, headers={}, API_LINK=API_LINK, key=False):
    headers[AUTH_STRING] = 'Gogo'
    call_api = API_LINK + project_name + api_extension
    response_api = requests.get(call_api, headers=headers, params=payload)

    if key: return project_name + ':' + response_api
    else: return response_api
```

While calling **fetch_api()** from the branch line, I want to pass payload as {'a':1} and key=True.

Please guide me to the direction or answer. Thanks. Using Python 3.3+.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can create a wrapper around `pool.starmap` that also accepts an iterator of over kwargs dictionaries.

```
from itertools import repeat

def starmap_with_kwargs(pool, fn, args_iter, kwargs_iter):
    args_for_starmap = zip(repeat(fn), args_iter, kwargs_iter)
    return pool.starmap(apply_args_and_kwargs, args_for_starmap)

def apply_args_and_kwargs(fn, args, kwargs):
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
```

Then you can call it in your case as:

```
args_iter = zip(repeat(project_name), api_extensions)
kwargs_iter = repeat(dict(payload={'a': 1}, key=True))
branches = starmap_with_kwargs(pool, fetch_api, args_iter, kwargs_iter)
```

Comment: Neat way to go!

Comment: I think that the function should be named like `starstarmap` :)