# No error message when applying list() to iterator in a multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, python-itertools

I am trying to implement starmap in a small python script I am writing. To do this I have been using the following answer to a stackoverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53173433/17456342). However, during the implementation process I encountered an issue I could not explain. Below I have attached code reproducing the issue of my original code.

```py
from itertools import repeat
import multiprocessing

# from stackexchange: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53173433/17456342
def starmap_with_kwargs(pool, fn, args_iter, kwargs_iter):
    args_for_starmap = zip(repeat(fn), args_iter, kwargs_iter)
    print(args_iter)
    return pool.starmap(apply_args_and_kwargs, args_for_starmap)

def apply_args_and_kwargs(fn, args, kwargs):
    print('test')
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)

def func(path, dictArg, **kwargs):
    for i in dictArg:
        print(i['a'])
        print(kwargs['yes'])

def funcWrapper(path, dictList, **kwargs):

    args_iter = zip(repeat(path), dictList)
    kwargs_iter = repeat(kwargs)

    # list(args_iter)

    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    starmap_with_kwargs(pool, func, args_iter, kwargs_iter)
       
    
dictList = [{'a: 2'}, {'a': 65}, {'a': 213}, {'a': 3218}]
path = 'some/path/to/something'

funcWrapper(path, dictList, yes=1)
```

The issue is the following: if I run the code above I get a TypeError message I expect should happen (this error is fixed by removing the loop in func). However, if I include the line `list(args_iter)` there is no error message and I have no idea why this happens, my issue then is **why is there no error message when list(args_iter) is included**?

I am using python 3.8.10 on ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS in WSL

Below I have attached the (expected) error message I get when I remove the line.

```py
<zip object at 0x7fa1ec0b8340>
test
test
test
test
multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback:
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 125, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 51, in starmapstar
    return list(itertools.starmap(args[0], args[1]))
  File "testing.py", line 67, in apply_args_and_kwargs
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "testing.py", line 71, in func
    print(i['a'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testing.py", line 88, in <module>
    funcWrapper(path, dictList, yes=1)
  File "testing.py", line 82, in funcWrapper
    starmap_with_kwargs(pool, func, args_iter, kwargs_iter)
  File "testing.py", line 61, in starmap_with_kwargs
    return pool.starmap(apply_args_and_kwargs, args_for_starmap)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 372, in starmap
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, starmapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 771, in get
    raise self._value
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with multiprocessing.  It has to do with how Python iterators work.  They only work once, and after that they are empty.

`zip` is iterator.  You bind it to the variable args_iter here:

```
args_iter = zip(repeat(path), dictList)
```

That's not necessarily a problem.  But when you run this line:

```
list(args_iter)
```

The iterator executes and puts its items into a list.  After you do that, the iterator is now exhausted.  When you later pass it to `starmap_with_args`, it's empty.

If you comment out the line where you turn args_iter into a list, then of course the iterator doesn't get used.

Check out this little script:

```
x = (0, 1, 2)
y = "ABC"
zipper = zip(x, y)

list(zipper)

for n, s in zipper:
    print(n, s)
```

This will not print out anything at all.  However, if you comment out the line

```
list(zipper)
```

the script will then produce this output:

```
0 A
1 B
2 C
```

Answer (score 0):

Check variable dictArg type passed to func(path, dictArg, **kwargs):

```
print(i['a'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Modify func to see arguments it gets:

```
def func(path, dictArg, **kwargs):
    print('func got:', path, dictArg, kwargs)
    """for i in dictArg:
        print(i['a'])
        print(kwargs['yes'])"""
```

func got: some/path/to/something {'a: 2'} {'yes': 1}, dictArg iteration provides keys, string 'a' in your case.

Comment: It might be that I am misunderstanding your answer, but this error I expect because I have intentionally left the error there so that I should get an error message if I keep list(args_iter) -- which I do not get and that is what I am confused about.